# How to add range of ports in firewall-cmd direct rule

Tags: rhel7, firewalld

I want to add a range of OUTPUT chain ports using firewall-cmd using its direct rule method, something like this:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=80-1000 -j ACCEPT
```

This says `success` however not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma, i.e. `--dport 80,1000`.

That said, using direct rules is discouraged (your command returns 'success' because `firewall-cmd` doesn't check the directly entered `iptables` syntax -- it assumes you have the rule correct). Man page says:

`Direct options should be used only as a last resort when it's not possible to use for example --add-service=service or --add-rich-rule='rule'.`

See [Configuring Complex Firewall Rules with the "Rich Language" Syntax](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-configuring_firewalld#Configuring_Complex_Firewall_Rules_with_the_Rich-Language_Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The below command will accept traffic from ports 22,53 and 80 (see [source](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3802/How-to-allow-or-block-the-port-and-IP-Address-using-Firewalld-IP-tables-and-UFW-in-Linux.html)):

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 22,53,80 -j ACCEPT
```

I prefer this variation with reload required for permanent rules only:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 22,53,80 -j ACCEPT && sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```